# could someone please give an concrete example to illustrate what does Multiplicity mean in the context of Bag-of-words model?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, bag-of-words

This [CMU Machine Learning Course](https://youtu.be/Mq0UpzWMe_o?t=1426) is using the Bag-of-words model without too much explanation.

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) uses the term **multiplicity** to explain that model.

> The bag-of-words model is a simplifying representation used in natural language processing and information retrieval (IR). In this model, a text (such as a sentence or a document) is represented as the bag (multiset) of its words, disregarding grammar and even word order but keeping **multiplicity**.

the link to explain multiplicity is in mathematical perspective, could someone please give a concrete example to explain multiplicity of Bag-of-words model in NLP perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplicity means keeping track of counts.

A set keeps track of whether something is in it or not.

Multiset additionally contains information of **how many times** something belongs to it.

In the context of bag of words it means that you count duplicates - this is for example important if you want to use different versions of Naive Bayes algorithm (Bernoulli vs Multinomial Naive Bayes).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring multiplicity (i.e., multiples instances of the same word) leads to a regular [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)):

$$\text{go to the store to get the milk} \implies
\{ \text{get}, \text{go}, \text{milk}, \text{store}, \text{the}, \text{to} \}.$$

Keeping multiplicity (i.e., multiples instances of the same word) leads to a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset):

$$\text{go to the store to get the milk} \implies
\{ \text{get}, \text{go}, \text{milk}, \text{store}, \text{the}, \text{the}, \text{to}, \text{to} \}.$$

(Note that a set can be represented by a list of items where order is ignored, and a multiset can be represented equivalently by a list of items accompanied by their counts, where order is ignored.  Thus, depending on the particular representation being used, your bag-of-words model might look a bit different to what I have shown above.)